# Mouse trapped in a box with 3 exits - DTMC problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

A mouse is trapped in a box, with 3 exits. Exit 1 leads back to the box in 3 steps,
Exit 2 leads back to the box in 1 step and Exit 3 never leads back to the box. The mouse chooses the exit at random. Define a Markov chain that describes the problem and derive its transition matrix.

> Attempt. We need to define $\{X_n\}$ such that $X_{n+1}$ is determined by only
> $X_n$ and not its predessecors. $X_n$ being equal to $1$ if the mouse is in the box and $0$ otherwise is not suitable for our problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you need to keep track of the location of the mouse, because every chosen exit has different consequences. If we would have that Exit 1 would lead back to the box in one step, the following diagram could be used:

[image]

In that case you have four states: $0$ (box), $1$ (exit 1), $2$ (exit 2) and $3$ (exit 3). From state $0$ you go to the three other states with equal probability. If you enter state $3$, you do not return. If you enter state $1$ or $2$, you return back to the box (state $0$).

The problem states that you only return from exit 1 to the box in 3 steps. Therefore, if the mouse chooses exit 1, you have to keep track of the number of steps already taken, to make the chain Markovian. This is not possible with the current states, forcing us to extend the state space with states that keep track of the number of steps if the mouse has chosen exit 1. One way to add a step is via the following scheme, which can be extended to include more steps:

[image]